# Plugging edited Datatable values in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt, datatables-1.10

I am trying to understand how to use the values from an edited data table and do some calculation.

I have a data frame which loads by default. When you click on 'run' it updates the tables based on the input value.

I want the user to edit the values manually in the table and then click on 'run'. Next, I want the app to take the edited values in the data table, run some calculations, and update the table. In this way the user can dynamically see the result their input makes on the table.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

#### Module 1 renders the first table
tableMod <- function(input, output, session, modelRun,modelData,budget){

  output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    modelRun()
    isolate(
      datatable(
        modelData %>% 
          mutate(New_Membership  = as.numeric(Modified * 0.01)*(budget())),
        selection = 'none', editable = TRUE
      )
    )
  })
  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
    df[input$x1_cell_edit$row,input$x1_cell_edit$col] <<- input$x1_cell_edit$value
  })
}
tableUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  dataTableOutput(ns("x1"))
}

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    tableUI("opfun"),
    numericInput("budget_input", "Total Forecast", value = 2),
    actionButton("opt_run", "Run")
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df <- data.frame(Channel = c("A", "B","C"),
                   Current = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                   Modified = c(2500, 3500,3000),
                   New_Membership = c(450, 650,700),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  callModule( tableMod,"opfun",
              modelRun = reactive(input$opt_run),
              modelData = df,
              budget = reactive(input$budget_input))

  observeEvent(input$opt_run, {
    cat('HJE')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Comment: If I run your code and click on the "Run" button nothing changes, even if I change the value of "Total Forecast". So in which column would you like to edit values? Even better, what is your desired output?

Comment: I want the calculated values to be updated in `New_Membership` column.

Comment: Based on your data frame and formula: `df %>% mutate(New_Membership = ((as.numeric(Modified) - as.numeric(Current)*(input$budget_input/10))/10))` How did you get the value of 210, 290 and 220?

Comment: Yes, based on the formula it should update that column. Considering the value for `input$budget` is `2`

Comment: Yes update the column, but how did you come up to a value of 210, 290, 220 in your column "New_Membership"?

Comment: The data frame`df <- data.frame(Channel = c("A", "B","C"),
                 Current = c("2000", "3000","4000"),
                 Modified = c("2500", "3500","3000"),
                 New_Membership = c("450", "650","700"))`
And then formula
      `df %>% mutate(New_Membership = ((as.numeric(Modified) - as.numeric(Current)*(2/10))/10))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189144/discussion-between-miha-and-snt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A clean solution (rather than assigning values in other environments) would be to use a `reactiveVal` in your module which is in sync with the `datatable`. You can return this `reactive` from your module to make use of it also in the main application:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

#### Module 1 renders the first table
tableMod <- function(input, output, session, modelRun, modelData, budget){

  df <- reactiveVal(modelData) ## this variable will be in sync with your datatable

  output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    modelRun()
    isolate(
      datatable(
        df() %>% ## ...you always use the synced version here
          mutate(New_Membership  = as.numeric(Modified * 0.01)*(budget())),
        selection = 'none', editable = TRUE
      )
    )
  })


  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, { 
    new_df <- df()
    row <- input$x1_cell_edit$row
    col <- input$x1_cell_edit$col
    value <- as.numeric(input$x1_cell_edit$value)
    new_df[row, col] <- value
    df(new_df) ## ...and you make sure that 'df' stays in sync
  })

  list(updated_df = df) ## ...finally you return it to make use of it in the main app too
}
tableUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  dataTableOutput(ns("x1"))
}

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    tableUI("opfun"),
    numericInput("budget_input", "Total Forecast", value = 2),
    actionButton("opt_run", "Run")
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df <- data.frame(Channel = c("A", "B","C"),
                   Current = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                   Modified = c(2500, 3500,3000),
                   New_Membership = c(450, 650,700),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  result <- callModule( tableMod,"opfun",
              modelRun = reactive(input$opt_run),
              modelData = df,
              budget = reactive(input$budget_input))

  observeEvent(input$opt_run, {
    str(result$updated_df())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Comment: This is definitely cleaner approach

Answer (score 3):

This should work, but not the "cleanest" implementation:

I had to take `df` out of shiny to make your code work. Used `assign` to replace `df` in global environment (not the best idea...) once datatable is edited. But, data is not recalculated untill `Run` is pressed. Once `Run` is pressed modelData is overwritten: (`modelData <- df`). Again not the best idea, probably making `modelData` reactive will be better idea.

Also, have a look at `DT::replaceData`. It might be better idea than regenerating full table.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Channel = c("A", "B","C"),
                 Current = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                 Modified = c(2500, 3500,3000),
                 New_Membership = c(450, 650,700),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#### Module 1 renders the first table
tableMod <- function(input, output, session, modelRun,modelData,budget){


  observeEvent( input$x1_cell_edit, {
    cat ('input$x1_cell_edit \n')
    info = input$x1_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    df[i, j] <- DT:::coerceValue(v, df[i, j])
    assign("df", df, envir = .GlobalEnv)

  })

  output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    modelRun()
    modelData <- df
    isolate(
      datatable(
        modelData %>% 
          mutate(New_Membership  = as.numeric(Modified * 0.01)*(budget())),
        selection = 'none', editable = TRUE
      )
    )
  })


}
tableUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  dataTableOutput(ns("x1"))
}

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    tableUI("opfun"),
    numericInput("budget_input", "Total Forecast", value = 2),
    actionButton("opt_run", "Run")
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  callModule( tableMod,"opfun",
              modelRun = reactive(input$opt_run),
              modelData = df,
              budget = reactive(input$budget_input))

  observeEvent(input$opt_run, {
    cat('HJE')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```